# Local firebase emulator - Callable function cannot access realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I created a callable function that stores some values to the realtime database. When I push the function to the firebase server everything works fine.

For development, I wanted to use a local emulator but whenever I call a function that saves values to a realtime database it doesn't work.

Note: If I create a function that saves a value to firestore it works fine

**Error**

```
10:05:52
I
function[testFirebase]
Beginning execution of "testFirebase"
10:05:52
I
function[testFirebase]
Finished "testFirebase" in ~1s
10:05:53
I
function[testFirebase]
Beginning execution of "testFirebase"
10:05:54
I
function[testFirebase]
Finished "testFirebase" in ~1s
10:06:40
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
Beginning execution of "testRealtimeDb"
10:06:40
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
Finished "testRealtimeDb" in ~1s
10:06:40
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
Beginning execution of "testRealtimeDb"
10:06:41
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
[2020-05-30T15:06:41.036Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."} 
10:06:41
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
[2020-05-30T15:06:41.144Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."} 
10:06:41
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
[2020-05-30T15:06:41.247Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."} 
10:06:41
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
[2020-05-30T15:06:41.872Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."} 
10:06:42
I
function[testRealtimeDb]
[2020-05-30T15:06:42.406Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}
```

**Function Definition**

```
// Function that saves to realtime db
functions.https.onCall((async (data, context) => {
  await admin.database().ref('TEST_PROPERTY').set(data)
  return data;
}));

// Function that saves to firestore - works locally and in server
functions.https.onCall((async (data, context) => {
  await admin.firestore().doc('TEST_PROPERTY').set(data)
  return data;
}));
```

**Firebase Admin Initialization (Using typescript)**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()
```

Comment: can you show us how you initialize firebase-admin? More specifically, your `admin.initializeApp()`

Comment: Added the code to question. But I am calling just calling `admin.initializeApp()`

Comment: If the issue has not been solved yet, check [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#database) of documentation on how to use emulator.